# nvcc error: string_view.h: constexpr function return is non-constant

Tags: c++, tensorflow, nvcc

I'm trying to compile some TensorFlow native op with CUDA code.
I'm using Python 3.6 and TensorFlow 1.11 here, and CUDA 8.0, on Ubuntu 16.

More specifically:

```
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 
GNU C++11 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
```

**Edit:** I repeated the experiment with CUDA 9.0 and CUDA 9.1, and also various compiler backends, via `-compiler-bindir clang++` or `-compiler-bindir gcc-4.8`, and it's always the same error.

test.cu:

```
// For Eigen::GpuDevice.
#define EIGEN_USE_GPU 1

// For Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice.
#define EIGEN_USE_THREADS 1

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device.h"

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <math_constants.h>

#include "tensorflow/core/platform/stream_executor.h"
```

Compiling:

```
$ /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -shared -O2 -std=c++11 -I /u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include -I /u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/nsync/public -I /usr/local/cuda-8.0/include -L /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -x cu -DGOOGLE_CUDA=1 -Xcompiler -fPIC -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -g test.cu -o test.so -lblas -lf77blas -L/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/.libs -lopenblasp-r0-8dca6697.3.0.dev -L/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow -ltensorflow_framework
```

(Add `-v -Xcompiler -v` to get some more compiler version info, although that does not seem related here.)

Output:

```
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(55): warning: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(309): warning: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(310): warning: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/absl/strings/string_view.h(501): error: constexpr function return is non-constant

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1255): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("real") from a __host__ __device__ function("abs") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1255): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("imag") from a __host__ __device__ function("abs") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1260): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("real") from a __host__ __device__ function("abs") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1260): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("imag") from a __host__ __device__ function("abs") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1285): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("real") from a __host__ __device__ function("exp") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1286): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("imag") from a __host__ __device__ function("exp") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1287): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("imag") from a __host__ __device__ function("exp") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1293): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("real") from a __host__ __device__ function("exp") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1294): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("imag") from a __host__ __device__ function("exp") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h(1295): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("imag") from a __host__ __device__ function("exp") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/lib/bfloat16/bfloat16.h(72): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("real") from a __host__ __device__ function("bfloat16") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/lib/bfloat16/bfloat16.h(75): warning: calling a constexpr __host__ function("real") from a __host__ __device__ function("bfloat16") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h(124): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "tensorflow::GetTensorSpatialDims"

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h(148): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "tensorflow::GetTensorDimsFromSpatialDims"

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework/function.h(618): warning: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework/function.h(619): warning: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(651): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(855): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(2096): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::igamma_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::igamma(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=float]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsHalf.h(34): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(712): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(863): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(2096): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::igamma_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::igamma(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=float]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsHalf.h(34): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(651): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]" 
(855): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]" 
(2102): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::igamma_der_a_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::igamma_der_a(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=float]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsHalf.h(38): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(712): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]" 
(863): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]" 
(2102): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::igamma_der_a_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::igamma_der_a(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=float]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsHalf.h(38): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(651): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]" 
(855): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]" 
(2108): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::gamma_sample_der_alpha_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::gamma_sample_der_alpha(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=float]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsHalf.h(42): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(712): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]" 
(863): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]" 
(2108): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::gamma_sample_der_alpha_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::gamma_sample_der_alpha(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=float]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsHalf.h(42): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(651): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(855): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(2096): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::igamma_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::igamma(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=double]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/arch/CUDA/CudaSpecialFunctions.h(120): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(712): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(863): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(2096): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::igamma_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::igamma(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=double]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/arch/CUDA/CudaSpecialFunctions.h(120): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(651): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]" 
(855): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]" 
(2102): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::igamma_der_a_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::igamma_der_a(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=double]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/arch/CUDA/CudaSpecialFunctions.h(135): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(712): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]" 
(863): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::DERIVATIVE]" 
(2102): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::igamma_der_a_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::igamma_der_a(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=double]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/arch/CUDA/CudaSpecialFunctions.h(135): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(651): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]" 
(855): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]" 
(2108): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::gamma_sample_der_alpha_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::gamma_sample_der_alpha(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=double]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/arch/CUDA/CudaSpecialFunctions.h(154): here

/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(712): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_series_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]" 
(863): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=double, mode=Eigen::internal::SAMPLE_DERIVATIVE]" 
(2108): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::gamma_sample_der_alpha_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::gamma_sample_der_alpha(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=double]" 
/u/zeyer/py-envs/py36-tf111/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/arch/CUDA/CudaSpecialFunctions.h(154): here

1 error detected in the compilation of "/var/tmp/tmpxft_000021f3_00000000-9_test.cpp1.ii".
```

The main error seems to be this:

```
absl/strings/string_view.h(501): error: constexpr function return is non-constant
```

Looking at that code in `string_view.h`:

```
static constexpr size_type CheckLengthInternal(size_type len) {
  return ABSL_ASSERT(len <= kMaxSize), len;
}
```

Where `ABSL_ASSERT` is defined (in `absl/base/macros.h`) as:

```
// ABSL_ASSERT()
//
// In C++11, `assert` can't be used portably within constexpr functions.
// ABSL_ASSERT functions as a runtime assert but works in C++11 constexpr
// functions.  Example:
//
// constexpr double Divide(double a, double b) {
//   return ABSL_ASSERT(b != 0), a / b;
// }
//
// This macro is inspired by
// https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/05/18/asserts-in-constexpr-functions/
#if defined(NDEBUG)
#define ABSL_ASSERT(expr) (false ? (void)(expr) : (void)0)
#else
#define ABSL_ASSERT(expr)              \
  (ABSL_PREDICT_TRUE((expr)) ? (void)0 \
                             : [] { assert(false && #expr); }())  // NOLINT
#endif
```

Any suggestion what the problem might be? And how to resolve it?

Compiling the same file directly with `g++` works. So this is specifically a problem with the nvcc frontend (`cudafe`).

**Edit:** I think this might actually be a bug in TensorFlow (or the absl library), so I reported it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22766). Or it might be a bug in `cudafe`. (But actually, I think the error looks valid, as this is really not a constant expression, and the `ABSL_ASSERT` workaround/hack described [here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/05/18/asserts-in-constexpr-functions/) might not work here.)

Comment: Did you read the compiler info? -> "The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this."

Comment: @HugoMaxwell: This compiler info is about the warning, not about the error.

Comment: I hit the same problem, and adding `DNDEBUG` would only lead to another issue ```string_view.h(492): error: calling a __host__ function("__builtin_strlen") from a __device__ function("absl::string_view::StrLenInternal") is not allowed
```

Comment: Adding the `-DNDEBUG` flag to nvcc resolved this issue for me. TF 1.12, python 3.6, CUDA 9.0, CuDNN 7.3, g++ 4.8, Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **-DNDEBUG** could also resolved my problem. TF 1.13, python 3.6, CUDA 10.0, CuDNN 7.6, g++ 4.8, CentOS-7

Comment: You find some more solutions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22766).